# How to get nice formatting in the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I want to get something like this to look nice:

```
>> ProductColor.all
=> [#<ProductColor id: 1, name: "White", internal_name: "White", created_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44", updated_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44">, #<ProductColor id: 2, name: "Ivory", internal_name: "Ivory", created_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44", updated_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44">, #<ProductColor id: 3, name: "Blue", internal_name: "Light Blue", created_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44", updated_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44">, #<ProductColor id: 4, name: "Green", internal_name: "Green", created_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44", updated_at: "2009-06-10 04:02:44">]
```

This doesn't work:

```
>> ProductColor.all.inspect
=> "[#<ProductColor id: 1, name: \"White\", internal_name: \"White\", created_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\", updated_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\">, #<ProductColor id: 2, name: \"Ivory\", internal_name: \"Ivory\", created_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\", updated_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\">, #<ProductColor id: 3, name: \"Blue\", internal_name: \"Light Blue\", created_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\", updated_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\">, #<ProductColor id: 4, name: \"Green\", internal_name: \"Green\", created_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\", updated_at: \"2009-06-10 04:02:44\">]"
```

And neither does this:

```
>> ProductColor.all.to_yaml
=> "--- \n- !ruby/object:ProductColor \n  attributes: \n    name: White\n    created_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    updated_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    id: \"1\"\n    internal_name: White\n  attributes_cache: {}\n\n- !ruby/object:ProductColor \n  attributes: \n    name: Ivory\n    created_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    updated_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    id: \"2\"\n    internal_name: Ivory\n  attributes_cache: {}\n\n- !ruby/object:ProductColor \n  attributes: \n    name: Blue\n    created_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    updated_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    id: \"3\"\n    internal_name: Light Blue\n  attributes_cache: {}\n\n- !ruby/object:ProductColor \n  attributes: \n    name: Green\n    created_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    updated_at: 2009-06-10 04:02:44\n    id: \"4\"\n    internal_name: Green\n  attributes_cache: {}\n\n"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

The `y` method is a handy way to get some pretty YAML output.

```
y ProductColor.all
```

Assuming you are in `script/console`

As jordanpg commented, this answer is outdated. For Rails 3.2+ you need to execute the following code before you can get the `y` method to work:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

From [ruby-docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html)

> In older Ruby versions, ie. <= 1.9, Syck is still provided, however it
>   was completely removed with the release of Ruby 2.0.0.

For rails 4/ruby 2 you could use just

```
puts object.to_yaml
```

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer since it's built in, can be used immediately, and most of all, simple.

Comment: This answer is outdated.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571801/rails-console-y-helper-returns-nameerror-rather-than-yaml-formatting-output  To make this work, you have to first execute `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'`.

Comment: Its now YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'

Comment: This is similar to ryanb

 >> ProductColor.all
 >> y _

Comment: like @botbot said above, this is the best answer since it applies to situations where you ahve no access to an `.irbrc`, other console tools, or other configurations of the console (like, being a contracted dev with limited access to a production container/server)

Comment: y method coming from ruby and still available in 2.5. `irb(main):010:0> method(:y).source_location
=> ["/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/y.rb", 5]`

Answer (score 104):

You should try [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb/tree/master#readme). It's a gem made to to pretty format objects in the ruby console. Your script/console session would look like this:

```
>> require 'hirb'
=> true
>> Hirb.enable
=> true
>> ProductColor.first
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name  | internal_name | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | White | White         | 2009-06-10 04:02:44 | 2009-06-10 04:02:44 |
+----+-------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set
=> true
```

You can learn more about hirb at its [homepage](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/).

Comment: ryanb's answer is basically what I was looking for, but this is too cool not to accept.

Comment: While not an answer to the original question, it might be pointing out that you can add the hirb stuff to your ~/.irbrc so you don't have to require and enable it each time.

Comment: This gem is outdated now .

Comment: Is there a way to "easily" sort the columns of the output? I would love to force the column id to be first and updated_at & created_at at the end (if you add columns after the first migration the updated_at & created_at columns will not be at the end)

Answer (score 35):

[Awesome print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) is nice too if you want an object indented. Something like:

```
$ rails console
rails> require "awesome_print"
rails> ap Account.all(:limit => 2)
[
    [0] #<Account:0x1033220b8> {
                     :id => 1,
                :user_id => 5,
            :assigned_to => 7,
                   :name => "Hayes-DuBuque",
                 :access => "Public",
                :website => "http://www.hayesdubuque.com",
        :toll_free_phone => "1-800-932-6571",
                  :phone => "(111)549-5002",
                    :fax => "(349)415-2266",
             :deleted_at => nil,
             :created_at => Sat, 06 Mar 2010 09:46:10 UTC +00:00,
             :updated_at => Sat, 06 Mar 2010 16:33:10 UTC +00:00,
                  :email => "info@hayesdubuque.com",
        :background_info => nil
    },
    [1] #<Account:0x103321ff0> {
                     :id => 2,
                :user_id => 4,
            :assigned_to => 4,
                   :name => "Ziemann-Streich",
                 :access => "Public",
                :website => "http://www.ziemannstreich.com",
        :toll_free_phone => "1-800-871-0619",
                  :phone => "(042)056-1534",
                    :fax => "(106)017-8792",
             :deleted_at => nil,
             :created_at => Tue, 09 Feb 2010 13:32:10 UTC +00:00,
             :updated_at => Tue, 09 Feb 2010 20:05:01 UTC +00:00,
                  :email => "info@ziemannstreich.com",
        :background_info => nil
    }
]
```

To integrate it by default with your irb/rails/pry console, add to your `~/.irbrc` or `~/.pryrc` file:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb! # just in .irbrc
AwesomePrint.pry! # just in .pryrc
```

Comment: Can I use this gem with Rails 4 or 5 ?? I've found the following note in the github page: NOTE: awesome_print v1.2.0 is the last release supporting Ruby versions prior to v1.9.3 and Rails versions prior to v3.0. The upcoming awesome_print v2.0 will require Ruby v1.9.3 or later and Rails v3.0 or later. Does this mean that the gem is outdated with these versions and cause conflicts??

Answer (score 14):

```
>> puts ProductColor.all.to_yaml
```

Simply works fine!

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830096

Comment: This works great! I couldn't get the other top voted answers to work... I guess because I am using ActiveResource (API resources)

Answer (score 10):

May also be noted that you can use:

```
j ProductColor.all.inspect
```

to output in Json format rather than Yaml

Comment: this can fail depending on version of JSON/ruby, and the nice formatting may be needed in an environment where one cant have nice things

Comment: This raise error: JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed

Answer (score 9):

I think this solution is the most accurate one. You should try this:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate Entry.all.map(&:attributes)
```

This will give you a super nice output compare to YAML format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 44,
    "team_id": null,
    "member_id": 1000000,
    "match_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-09 15:53:14 +0900",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-09 15:53:14 +0900"
  },
  {
    "id": 45,
    "team_id": null,
    "member_id": 1000001,
    "match_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-09 15:53:36 +0900",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-09 15:53:36 +0900"
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "team_id": null,
    "member_id": 1000003,
    "match_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-09 15:56:40 +0900",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-09 15:56:40 +0900"
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "team_id": null,
    "member_id": 1000004,
    "match_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-09 15:56:48 +0900",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-09 15:56:48 +0900"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Hi you can also try this in your script/console if

```
>> y ProductColor.all
```

not working for you.

**Try this:**

```
>> require 'yaml'

>> YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```

**then**

```
>> y ProductColor.all
```

Answer (score 7):

I had some troubles making it work so I'll add my two cents to awesome_print
add this to your Gemfile, preferably in `:development`

`gem 'awesome_print', require: 'ap'`

then in

`rails console`

you can do

`> ap Model.all`
That's it.  However you can also add

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

to your ~/.irbrc,  this way awesome_print will be required anytime you open the console and you can simply do

Model.all
without the need of typing ap

Answer (score 6):

You may also try the following for a group of objects

```
Object.all.map(&:attributes).to_yaml
```

This will give you *much nicer* output, like

```
---
id: 1
type: College
name: University of Texas
---
id: 2
type: College
name: University of California
```

**Calling `to_yaml` on attributes rather than the object itself saves you from viewing the full contents of the object in the output**

Or `puts Object.last.attributes.to_yaml` for a single object

Shorthand is also available: `y Object.last.attributes`

Answer (score 5):

Use `irbtools` gem.

It will automatically format the the console output plus you'll get tons of great features.

Comment: Nice! But I can't get it to format ActiveResource content... unless I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 4):

You might want to define ProductColor's inspect method to return something that you find nice. For example:

```
def inspect
  "<#{id} - #{name} (#{internal_name})>"
end
```

After which the result of ProductColor.all will display as something like [<1 - White (White)>, ...]. Of course you should adjust the inspect method to your needs, so that it displays all the information you need in a style that you like.

Edit: also if the issue was the lack of line breaks in the output, you might try

```
require 'pp'
pp ProductColor.all
```

which should insert linebreaks where appropriate

Comment: As a matter of fact `require 'pp'` isn't possible in `rails console --sandbox`. For some reason I get `false` when I try to require `pp`. Oops! it seems that `pp` is already required by default in `rails console`. I just did `pp Model.connection_handler` and got big pretty printed output. Thanks.

Comment: @Green If `require` returns `false`, that just means that the file has been loaded already.

Comment: Why the `inspect` is not displayed when doing just `ProductColor.all`?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Alter Lago's suggestion for using AwesomePrint,
If you can't/shouldn't/don't want to add the awesome_print gem to your project's Gemfile, do this:

`gem install awesome_print`

Edit ~/.irb.rc and add this:

`$LOAD_PATH << '/Users/your-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/awesome_print-1.1.0/lib'`

`require 'awesome_print'`

(Making sure the path and version are correct, of course)