# Ruby Configure IRB to Pretty_Inspect by Default

Tags: ruby, default, pretty-print, irb, inspect

I'm fairly new to ruby, and am configuring IRB. I like pretty print (require 'pp'), but it seems a hassle to always type pp  for it to pretty print it. What I'd like to do is make it pretty print by default, so if i have a var , say, 'myvar', and type myvar, it automatically calls pretty_inspect instead of the regular inspect. Where do I get started? Ideally, I would be able to add a method to my .irbrc file that is automatically called. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty printing objects by default in irb is exactly what [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb#readme) was made to do. [These](http://tagaholic.me/2009/10/15/boson-and-hirb-interactions.html#hirbs_handy_tables) [posts](http://tagaholic.me/2009/03/13/hirb-irb-on-the-good-stuff.html) explain how hirb can convert pretty much anything into an ascii table. Although hirb is meant to be configured per class, you could have all objects displayed as tables:

```
# put this in ~/.irbrc
require 'rubygems'
require 'hirb'
Hirb.enable :output=>{'Object'=>{:class=>:auto_table, :ancestor=>true}}

# in irb
>> %w{three blind mice}
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| three |
| blind |
| mice  |
+-------+
3 rows in set

>> 1..5
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 4     |
| 5     |
+-------+
5 rows in set

>> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
+---+---+
2 rows in set
```

[This related overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224525/how-to-get-nice-formatting-in-the-rails-console/1226006) also has an example of hirb in action.

Answer (score 1):

when irb starts, it reads .irbrc from your $HOME directory. If you edit (or create) that file and add

```
require 'pp'
```

it will be loaded each time you start irb.

Check out [this addition](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2916) to pretty_print method lists too. Toss that in your .irbrc and you can do :

```
>> 5.pm
                      %(arg1)         Fixnum
                      &(arg1)         Fixnum
                      *(arg1)         Fixnum
                     **(arg1)         Fixnum
                      +(arg1)         Fixnum
                     +@()             Fixnum(Numeric)
                      -(arg1)         Fixnum
                     -@()             Fixnum
                      /(arg1)         Fixnum
                     <<(arg1)         Fixnum
                     >>(arg1)         Fixnum
                     [](arg1)         Fixnum
                      ^(arg1)         Fixnum
                    abs()             Fixnum
                    ago(arg1, ...)    Fixnum(ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Time)
               between?(arg1, arg2)   Fixnum(Comparable)
                   byte()             Fixnum(ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Bytes)
                  bytes()             Fixnum(ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Bytes
```