# How do I print out the contents of an object in Rails for easy debugging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I'm trying to get the PHP equivalent of `print_r()` (print human-readable); at present the raw output is:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10355d1c0
```

What should I do?

Comment: In case you didn't see it (since you accepted an answer posted just before mine), do note that the debug() function works *exactly* like print_r() in PHP.

Comment: Just for anyone coming to this page later on debug() is outdated an not included as a function anymore.  Won't work.  (Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/users/231309/irongaze-com for pointing this out further down the page.)

Answer (score 252, accepted):

I generally first try `.inspect`, if that doesn't give me what I want, I'll switch to `.to_yaml`.

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end

user = User.new
user.name = "John Smith"
user.age = 30

puts user.inspect
#=> #<User:0x423270c @name="John Smith", @age=30>
puts user.to_yaml
#=> --- !ruby/object:User
#=> age: 30
#=> name: John Smith
```

Comment: I've found that some YAML outputs of records display more data (metadata, perhaps?) than I care to see. If I'm looking for the YAML version of a record I'll use `y record_name.attributes`. `#y` is an alias for `to_yaml`.

Answer (score 9):

define the to_s method in your model. For example

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    "Name:#{self.name} Age:#{self.age} Weight: #{self.weight}"
  end
end
```

Then when you go to print it with #puts it will display that string with those variables.

Comment: What if you don't know what the variables it contains are?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you saying, what if a variable is an array or hash? Their #to_s would take care of that.

Comment: This is not phrased correctly. `puts my_model_instance` will not call `to_s`. You will have to explicitly do that: `puts my_model_instance.to_s`

Answer (score 8):

I'm using the [awesome_print gem](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print)

So you just have to type :

```
ap @var
```

Comment: I'm not an advocate of installing a gem for something so simple, but I do use Awesome Print regularly.

Comment: This is really good, what I eventually did in my code is this: Rails.logger.ap someObject

Comment: gem install awesome_print (no edits needed to Gemfile)

Comment: gem super_awesome_print enhances ap. Stands out more in iTerm at least

Answer (score 8):

In Rails you can print the result in the View by using the debug' Helper [ActionView::Helpers::DebugHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html)

```
# app/view/controllers/post_controller.rb
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

#app/view/posts/index.html.erb
<%= debug(@posts) %>

#start your server
rails s
```

results (in browser)

```
- !ruby/object:Post
  raw_attributes:
    id: 2
    title: My Second Post
    body: Welcome!  This is another example post
    published_at: '2015-10-19 23:00:43.469520'
    created_at: '2015-10-20 00:00:43.470739'
    updated_at: '2015-10-20 00:00:43.470739'
  attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeSet
    attributes: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash
      types: &5
        id: &2 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Integer
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
          range: !ruby/range
            begin: -2147483648
            end: 2147483648
            excl: true
        title: &3 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::String
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
        body: &4 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::Text
          precision: 
          scale: 
          limit: 
        published_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: &1 !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime
            precision: 
            scale: 
            limit: 
        created_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *1
        updated_at: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter
          subtype: *1
```

Answer (score 6):

pp does the job too, no gem requiring is required.

```
@a = Accrual.first ; pp @a

#<Accrual:0x007ff521e5ba50
 id: 4,
 year: 2018,
 Jan: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e58f08,'0.11E2',9(27)>,
 Feb: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e585d0,'0.88E2',9(27)>,
 Mar: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e58030,'0.0',9(27)>,
 Apr: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e53698,'0.88E2',9(27)>,
 May: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e52fb8,'0.8E1',9(27)>,
 June: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e52900,'0.8E1',9(27)>,
 July: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e51ff0,'0.8E1',9(27)>,
 Aug: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e51bb8,'0.88E2',9(27)>,
 Sep: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e512f8,'0.88E2',9(27)>,
 Oct: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e506c8,'0.0',9(27)>,
 Nov: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e43d38,'0.888E3',9(27)>,
 Dec: #<BigDecimal:7ff521e43478,'0.0',9(27)>,
```

You can also print two instances of an object:

```
 pp( Accrual.first , Accrual.second)
`
`
`
```

Answer (score 3):

`inspect` is great but sometimes not good enough. E.g. `BigDecimal` prints like this: `#<BigDecimal:7ff49f5478b0,'0.1E2',9(18)>`.

To have full control over what's printed you could redefine `to_s` or `inspect` methods. Or create your own one to not confuse future devs too much.

```
  class Something < ApplicationRecord

    def to_s
      attributes.map{ |k, v| { k => v.to_s } }.inject(:merge)
    end

  end
```

This will apply a method (i.e. `to_s`) to all attributes. This example will get rid of the ugly `BigDecimals`.

You can also redefine a handful of attributes only:

```
  def to_s
    attributes.merge({ my_attribute: my_attribute.to_s })
  end
```

You can also create a mix of the two or [somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733125/2771889) add associations.

Answer (score 3):

`.inspect` is what you're looking for, it's way easier IMO than `.to_yaml`!

```
user = User.new
user.name = "will"
user.email = "will@example.com"

user.inspect
#<name: "will", email: "will@example.com">
```

Answer (score 2):

`instance.attributes` prints the whole hash inside rails console.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use `debug(@var)`. It's exactly like "print_r".

Comment: This is not a thing, at least on Ruby 1.9.x - NoMethodError: undefined method `debug' for main:Object