# The proper search result is not coming using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to access all values from Database according to `id` but i am getting the following output.

> Output:

```
all details are #<PaymentVendor:0x1ee5860>
all details are #<PaymentVendor:0x1f02798>
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
@rest_ids=[21,22,23]
@rest_ids.each do |ids|
            @pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(:id => ids )
            puts "all details are #{@pdf_vendor_details}"
        end
```

From the above code i have some array of ids(`i.e- @rest_ids`).Here my requirement is when the loop will execute as per id the record will fetch and store in the variable `@pdf_vendor_details` in array.If I wanted to display some value in table then i will be able to do that like below.

> table.html.erb:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Receipt No</td>
<td>Amount</td>
</tr>
 <% @pdf_vendor_details.each do |details| %>
<tr>
<td><%= details.id %></td>
<td><%= details.Receipt_No %></td>
<td><%= details.Amount %></td>
</tr>
<% end  %>
</table>
```

But doing this way i can not get any value and unable to display data in table.Please help me to access the data from `DB` which will store in array to display in table.

Comment: I have post the answer. please check n let me know if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(:id => @rest_ids ) #rails 4
#OR
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.find_all_by_id(@rest_ids) #rails 3    

@pdf_vendor_details.each do |pdf|
  puts "all details are: ID => #{pdf.id}, Receipt_No => #{pdf.Receipt_No}, Amount=> #{pdf.Amount}"
end
```

Your **`table.html.erb`** will be not changed

Comment: @ Gagan :Ok your line worked but i need another one help.I have one line `@pdf_address=Vendor.where(:v_name => @pdf_vendor_details.v_name , :s_catagory => @pdf_vendor_details.v_catagory )` in this line am getting the following error.
`undefined method `v_name' for #<Array:0x329d7c8>`
Where v_name always same for all id.

Comment: you are getting this error bcz you don't have field named `v_name` in `PaymentVendor` table. As you said its same for all then better to pass static.

Comment: @ Gagan : No,It has the field name `v_name ` in DB and i have to access the v_name from `@pdf_vendor_details.v_name`.

Comment: @rajat_474 : try this `@pdf_address=Vendor.where(:v_name => @pdf_vendor_details.map(&:v_name) , :s_catagory => @pdf_vendor_details.map(&:v_catagory))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
PaymentVendor.where(id: [21, 22, 23])
```

which will build a SQL statement like

```
SELECT * FROM payment_vendors WHERE id IN (21, 22, 23)
```

Comment: @ Aetherus : I dont want to set any static value.The id should be dynamic like `@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(:id => ids )`.That ids will contains all three ids.

Comment: PaymentVendor.where(id: @rest_ids)

Comment: @ Aetherus : No,no record is displaying on the table but this line is giving the output same as `all details are #<PaymentVendor:0x1f02798>`.

Comment: The `#<PaymentVendor:0x1f02798>` indicates that you got an instance (the `#`) of the class `PaymentVendor`, and its `object_id` is `0x1f02798`. If you want to see its attributes, call `to_hash` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason in looping @rest_ids and querying on each iteration

```
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(:id => ids )
```

and in each iteration you are replacing the previous value of @pdf_vendor_details instead of appending to the array.

Instead

```
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(id: @rest_ids ) #rails 4
```

or

```
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.find_all_by_id(@rest_ids) #rails 3
```

will do. It will send one query to fetch all records of paymentvendor in those ids'.

**Update:**

 If you want to print the contents of the object `@pdf_vendor_details` in raw form, you could use `.inspect` or `.to_yaml`.
For example, `puts @pdf_vendor_details.inspect`, will print the contents of the object.
Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829909/how-do-i-print-out-the-contents-of-an-object-in-rails-for-easy-debugging), to print contents of object.

```
@rest_ids=[21,22,23]
@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(id: @rest_ids )
puts "All details are, #{@pdf_vendor_details.inspect}"
```

Comment: @ BinaryMee :Actually it was a example(`i.e-@rest_ids=[21,22,23]`).In real case the id also will be dynamic that means `@rest_ids` is going to contain some array of ids.In this case how it will bw resolved.

Comment: You could dynamically fetch those array in an variable and you could pass it to the condition like @pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(id: @rest_ids)

Comment: @ BinaryMee : By doing this `@pdf_vendor_details = PaymentVendor.where(id: @rest_ids)` and when i checked the this lines o/p like `puts "all details are #{@pdf_vendor_details}"` it is giving the output the same `i.e-all details are #<PaymentVendor:0x1ee5860>`.

Comment: If you want to print contents of the object, you could use .inspect or .to_yaml to see the contents. For example, "all details are @pdf_vendor_details.inspect", will give you object's contents!