# Why I get NoMethodError by using to_yaml in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen the question about "[How do I print out the contents of an object in Rails for easy debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829909/how-do-i-print-out-the-contents-of-an-object-in-rails-for-easy-debugging?answertab=active#tab-top)", and the answer showed that I can use to_yaml to print out the contents of Object.
However, why I run the same code created by @jerhinesmith but get an NoMethodError?

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end

user = User.new
user.name = "John Smith"
user.age = 30

puts user.inspect
#=> #<User:0x423270c @name="John Smith", @age=30>
puts user.to_yaml
#=> --- !ruby/object:User
#=> age: 30
#=> name: John Smith
```

> main.rb:11:in `<main>': undefined method`to_yaml' for #
>
> @name="John Smith", @age=30> (NoMethodError) exited with non-zero
>   status

Comment: you can try with `y the_object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method won't be defined until you load in the YAML library with:

```
require 'yaml'
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I am new hand of Ruby. I only know to require, but forget to add the quotation mark on 'yaml'

Comment: The syntax is pretty forgiving, but it's still important. Hope that worked. If so, accept it as a solution when you can. Good luck!