# Rails console 'y' helper returns NameError rather than yaml-formatting output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console, to-yaml

I'm trying to use `y object` in Rails 3.2.6/Ruby 1.9.3 console to get nicely formatted yaml output for an ActiveRecord object, but for some reason it isn't working for me. I've used it in the past, but somewhere along the way it broke. I get the following output when I try:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `yaml' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `y` method is actually an extension to the `Kernel` object put in place by the [Syck YAML parser/emitter](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/syck/rdoc/Syck.html). Here are the last few lines of `lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb`:

```
module Kernel
    def y( object, *objects )
        objects.unshift object
        puts( if objects.length == 1
                  YAML.dump( *objects )
              else
                  YAML.dump_stream( *objects )
              end )
    end
    private :y
end
```

By default, Ruby 1.9.3 uses the [Psych parser/emitter](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/) instead of Syck (I can only presume they're pronounced differently), and Psych doesn't declare such a method.

If you really loved `y`, you can simply use Syck instead of Psych in the console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.5)
1.9.3p194 :001 > y 'hello'
NoMethodError: undefined method 'y' for main:Object
1.9.3p194 :002 > YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
"syck"
1.9.3p194 :003 > y 'hello'
--- hello
nil
```

I'll also use this chance to plug [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/), which does for basically everything what `y` does for YAML.

Comment: Love awesome_print! Thanks for the rec!

Comment: if you put that line (YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck') in your ~/.irbc then the 'y' method will always be available to you when you go to load irb or rails console

Answer (score 8):

For rails 4/ruby 2 you could use just

```
puts object.to_yaml
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing. But then I came across what I thought my be a shorthand using y object. I guess I was wrong :(